# I'm studying firebase in xcode, but I want to know how to distinguish login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm studying in "xcode".
I'm learning to log in using Firebase.
Is there any way to distinguish between email login and Google login?

The function that I want to implement is...
If you log in with your email/password,
I want to hide the password change button.

I can't do it the way I do it.

`let isemailSignIn = Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData[0].providerID == "password" resetPasswordButton.isHidden = !isemailSignIn`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, I think you want that when you click on email login button your reset Password button will hide ,

1. first make outlet of your resetPasswordButton and then you should write code where you dont want show your button like this ,

   resetButtonPassword.ishidden = true

and if you want hide button on specific text then you should write code like this ,

```
if textpassword.text == "password"{
     resetPasswordButton.isHidden = true
  }
   else {
             resetPasswordButton.isHidden = false
         }
```